# How can I extend my controller from installed Spree gem's controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, spree-auth-devise

I have `spree` gem installed successfully. I don't need `spree_frontend`. Here is the `Gemfile`

```
gem 'spree_core', '4.2.0.rc2'
gem 'spree_backend', '4.2.0.rc2'
gem 'spree_sample', '4.2.0.rc2'
gem 'spree_cmd', '4.2.0.rc2'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 4.2'
```

So I want to extend my `ApplicationController` from `Spree's BaseController`. Here is the code:

```
class ApplicationController < Spree::BaseController
  include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Order
end
```

But I get following errors:

```
uninitialized constant Spree::BaseController (NameError)
```

How can I extend my controller from installed Spree gem's controller?

Comment: class ApplicationController < ::Spree::BaseController

Comment: hey thank you for reply. but it's not work :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that `Spree::BaseController` already inherits from `ApplicationController`; see https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/controllers/spree/base_controller.rb.   This is to allow your `ApplicationController` to define things like `current_user` and similar basic functions before Spree sees it.

Declaring them the other way around *as well* creates a circular dependency, and the class loading fails as a result.  Without changing Spree itself, the only fix is to do something else.

Instead, to have your controllers use `Spree::BaseController` as a superclass,  first define `ApplicationController` in the more usual fashion e.g.:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ...
end
```

then invent a new abstract controller, for your own use, that inherits from Spree, e.g. let's name it `StoreBaseController`:

```
# app/controllers/store_base_controller.rb
class StoreBaseController < Spree::BaseController
  include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Order
  # ...
end
```

This `StoreBaseController` can now be used in place of `ApplicationController` when defining more specific controllers.  It works because it doesn't create a loop in the inheritance tree, which now looks like this:

[image: Controller Hierarchy]

Note: if you're also using the `rails generator` command to produce controllers or scaffolds from templates, be aware that the generator has `ApplicationController` hard-coded in the templates, so you'll need to amend them once created.

Comment: the same what I meant but better described :) Nice investigation

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you need to extend strictly `ApplicationController`?

I advise you alternative approach to create a new Base controller class, and then inherit all the children from it and leave `ApplicationController` to basic rails

`app/controller/my_base_controller.rb`

```rb
class MyBaseController < Spree::BaseController
  def foo
    # ...
  end
end
```

`app/controller/my_resources_controller.rb`

```rb
class MyResourcesController < MyBaseController
  def bar
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey thanks for reply. It's just example. My problem is I can't inherit my controller from `Spree::BaseController` See take a look at my question. When I inherit from `Spree:: BaseController` I get `uninitialized constant Spree::BaseController (NameError)` errors.

Comment: yes, because `ApplicationController` used internally by Rails, and while Rails trying to access it, you get undefined error. However if you fall down to your own custom controllers, that are not accessed by Rails internally, the error will be gone. I tested the following example, and it is ok. I just wanted to be sure, that there is no specific case to change inheritance for Rails `ApplicationController`

Answer (score 0):

As the errors states, `Spree::BaseController` is not defined within your app - it is defined in the `spree-core` gem. If you re-create the filepath to the base controller locally, that is `app/controllers/spree/`, and copy and paste the code from the controller into a local `base_controller.rb`, you can edit it and add custom functionality.

Note that it will still inherit from the `ApplicationController`, but you can place any of the code you wanted to put in the `ApplicationController` into here and have your classes inherit from `Spree::BaseContoller` and the effect will be the same.

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply. In `base_controller` there are tons of helpers, other controllers included. I can't copy and paste all of it. It's not a right way. Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

hmmm, I tried what you want to do but I succeeded (?)

```rb
class PagesController < Spree::BaseController
  include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Order
end
```

in the console

```rb
2.6.5 :006 > pp PagesController.ancestors
[PagesController,
 Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Order,
 #<Module:0x00007fca27610410>,
 Spree::BaseController,
 Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::CurrencyHelpers,
 Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::StrongParameters,
...
```

I'm using

- ruby 2.6.5
- rails 6.0.3.4
- run `bundle update` after adding the your spree's gems in the Gemfile

So I think its the requiring or auto-loading problem

- what's your rails version? 6? spree >= 4.1 should use rails >= 6
- Does Spree::BaseController exist in rails console?
- Is `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)` in `config/application.rb`?
- Does the gems included in the right group of the Gemfile? ex: spree gems are in :production group.
- Does it have `config.load_defaults 6.0` in `config/application.rb`?